# Android - É uma boa prática usar o strings.xml default para aplicativos nacionais?

Tags: android

Estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo para uma autoescola, minha dúvida é na questão da encodificação dos arquivos são todos UTF-8 por padrão ou apenas é aplicado para valores como values-pt-rBr? Minha preocupação é apenas se os caracteres especiais como ç ã é irão se manter intactos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Todos os arquivos XML são UTF-8, então em tese qualquer arquivo de qualquer idioma pode conter qualquer caractere.

Ideal ideal é que o idioma default seja inglês, mas autoescola realmente é um mercado que só tem no Brasil, então não vale a pena o esforço.

Answer (score 1):

A [documentação](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages?hl=pt-br) não define um idioma ideal para ser default e isso é compreensível, afinal de contas isso vai depender do projeto e das especificações do app.

Com relação aos caracteres especiais não precisa se preocupar como o **epx** falou.

Comment: Lucas, seria legal citar na resposta a parte do texto do link que confirma isso, para deixar bem documentado

Comment: Ricador, na verdade eu quis dizer que a documentação não determina qual linguagem deveria ser o default. Fiz uma edição na minha resposta para ficar mais claro.